# Python 3. Как внутри функции получить словарь переменных модуля из которого она была вызвана?

Tags: python

globals() не подходит, потому что даёт словарь переменных модуля где функция была инициализированна, что не всегда совпадает с местом вызова. Конечно можно каждый раз явно передавать vars() в функцию, но нет ли способа по-изящнее?

Comment: Ну, вообще-то по-хорошему переменные нужно в явном виде передавать в класс или функцию, всё остальное это какие-то левые хаки, так неправильно программы писать.

Answer (score 0):

```
""" @file funcs.py
"""
import sys

def function():
    try:
        depth = 1
        frame = sys._getframe(depth)
        while frame.f_code.co_name != "<module>":
            frame = sys._getframe(depth)
            depth += 1
        print(frame.f_globals)
    except ValueError:
        raise Exception("Не получилось определить вызывающий функцию модуль.")
```

---

```
""" @file __init__.py
"""
from funcs import function

def function_w(rec=50):
    # Увеличивает стек вызовов в function().
    if rec > 0:
        function_w(rec - 1)
    else:
        function()

hello = "world"
function_w()
```

---

В `function` с помощью [sys._getframe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) перебираем `frame`'ы из стека вызова до тех пор, пока не найдем модуль (идентифицируем его по имени `<module>`). После нахождения нам доступны его глобальные переменные через атрибут `f_globals`.